# Center / normalize choropleth colors in GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, matplotlib

I'm looking to plot a choropleth with a divergent colormap. I need to center the colormap in such a way that the middle color is displayed for a specific value (e.g. 0). How could I do this in GeoPandas/Geoplot?

I tried using a normalizer with `geopandas.plot()` but it's values are reset to data min and max once I plot:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.loc[:,'random'] = np.random.normal(size=len(world))+2

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(-4,4,clip=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
world.plot('random', cmap=cmap, legend=True, norm=norm, ax=ax)
```

And here is the figure:

[image: noncentered colors]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could normalize the color by using the `TwoSlopeNorm` function in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import geopandas as gpd

# generate data
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf = gdf[gdf.continent == 'Africa']
gdf['random'] = np.random.gamma(2, 2, len(gdf)) - 2

# normalize color
vmin, vmax, vcenter = gdf.random.min(), gdf.random.max(), 0
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=vmin, vcenter=vcenter, vmax=vmax)
# create a normalized colorbar
cmap = 'RdBu'
cbar = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 7))
# with no normalization
gdf.plot(column='random', cmap=cmap, legend=True, ax=ax1)

# with normalization
gdf.plot(column='random', cmap=cmap, norm=norm, legend=False, ax=ax2)
# add colorbar
fig.colorbar(cbar, ax=ax2)
```

[image]

**Notes:**

1. You could change `vcenter` to other desired values.
2. You need to normalize the color for the map and create a new normalized colorbar. Otherwise, they won't match with one another.
3. Set `legend=False` for the normalized map so that the unnormalized colorbar won't be plotted.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more, great answer!

Comment: Great answer. However, the code does not seem up to date. Therefore, I posted a follow-up [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/470456/97137).

Comment: @Stücke I tested it on my end, and it appears to still be functioning. What problem are you experiencing?