# GeoPandas colormap normalization for folium explore

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, folium, colormap

When creating static plots a GeoDataframe with matplotlib, I can use [colormap normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html) to plot data on a robust scale centered at zero. For example as shown in this question [Center / normalize choropleth colors in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330008/center-normalize-choropleth-colors-in-geopandas).

How do I achieve the same thing for a folium plot within the `.explore()` method of a GeoDataframe?